# HBase .META. table - readRequestsCount too high

Tags: apache, hadoop, mapreduce, hbase, apache-zookeeper

My HBase RegionServers are well balanced except the readRequestsCount to the .META. table.

Looking at the log files of my MapReduce jobs I found that there are many calls to ZooKeeper which established and closed immediately:

*2:04,958 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Initiating client connection, connectString=nam-1:2181,nam-2:2181,dat-4:2181 sessionTimeout=180000 watcher=catalogtracker-on-org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation@76477647
2014-02-04 20:32:04,958 
INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper: The identifier of this process is 16972@dat-2
2014-02-04 20:32:04,958 
INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server /1.10.230.132:2181
2014-02-04 20:32:04,958 
WARN org.apache.zookeeper.client.ZooKeeperSaslClient: SecurityException: java.lang.SecurityException: Unable to locate a login configuration occurred when trying to find JAAS configuration.
2014-02-04 20:32:04,958 
INFO org.apache.zookeeper.client.ZooKeeperSaslClient: Client will not SASL-authenticate because the default JAAS configuration section 'Client' could not be found. If you are not using SASL, you may ignore this. On the other hand, if you expected SASL to work, please fix your JAAS configuration.
2014-02-04 20:32:04,958 
INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Socket connection established to nam-1:2181, initiating session
2014-02-04 20:32:04,960 
INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session establishment complete on server nam-1:2181, sessionid = 0x243fd975d060d09, negotiated timeout = 60000
2014-02-04 20:32:05,430 
INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Session: 0x243fd975d060d09 closed*

I cant find any reason for that.
Anyone can help?

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try setting `hbase.zookeeper.property.maxClientCnxns` in hbase-site.xml. I set this to `150`  it works for me.